# Can I run cool-retro-term (or other visual shell programs) on WSL using Xming without requiring the original terminal to continue?

Tags: terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xming

I open up the WSL Ubuntu Bash, export DISPLAY=:0, and then fire up ./cool-retro-term; this works perfectly, but it by necessity crashes the CRT if I close the bash. Any tips on avoiding this?

Comment: Have you tried detaching it? [Detaching a running process from a bash shell | Daniel Beard's Programming Blog](https://danielbeard.wordpress.com/2011/06/08/detaching-a-running-process-from-a-bash-shell/)

Comment: Yup; stops output, but closing the term still kills it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `nohup ./cool-retro-term &`. That should do the trick. Nohup detaches the target process from the current bash terminal, and makes it immune to crashing when the terminal is **closed**. Note that I said closed, not `Ctrl-C`'ed. That's what the `&` is for. It moves the process to the background, so you don't have to worry about accidentally killing the process. After running this command, you can safely close CMD.